# response.write doesn't work node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm confused a lot. I receive POST data from browser, parse it and insert it in mysql. Everything works perfect, except the response to client after i inserted data. Response object is visible and it has method 'write' that simply refuses to work.

My code is below, thanks in advance.

```
var formidable = require("formidable");
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(request, function (error, fields, files) {
    if ( 'create' in fields ) {
        args.name = fields.create;
        if ( args.name == '' ) {
            response.writeHead( 500, {"Content-Type": 'text/html' } );
            response.end("this will work");
        };
        db.myFunction(args, function (id) {
            console.log(id); // shows correct data returned from function
            response.writeHead( 200, {"Content-Type": "text/html" } );
            console.log(response.headersSent); // true
            response.write(id); // but this will not work
            response.end(); 
            console.log('done'); // at this point node is still silent
        });
    } else {
        response.writeHead( 500, {"Content-Type": 'text/html' } );
        response.end("no create in fields"); // works fine
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `console.log('done')` also isn't working? FWIW, you probably want to do a `return` after `response.end("this will work")`.

Comment: @robertklep Actually I want to send back a chunk of data back to browser.
I'm not sure if I correctly understood your statement about placing 'return', since I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: I understand, but if the `console.log('done')` isn't working there might be some issue that will (also) cause your `response.write()` not to work.

Comment: The only thing could cause something is my database function. The code is below.
`function myFunction (args, callback) {
  connection.query("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES ('"+args.name+"') ", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    };
    var id = rows.insertId;
    callback(id);
  });
}`

Comment: Please add your code to the original question, comments make it hard to read.

Comment: What is `typeof id`? If it's not a string or Buffer, you should do something like `response.write(''+id);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data of `id` is probably not a String or a Buffer.
Try this: `response.write('' + id);`

Comment: Wow, yeah. It was my silly mistake. Worked for me perfectly.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would love for this to be a comment but first try to 
`response.write("some random string without the writeHead...")` if that works try:
`response.write(id.**toString()**)` still without the response.writeHead if that works try:
`response.write(id.toString())` you may also try `JSON.stringify(id)` but these are just strange solutions... I would really want to see all the code you have, for example where is your

```
    var express = require("express");
    var ejs = require("ejs");
    var app = express();
    app.set("view_engine", "ejs"); //or some other view engine like mustache
```

or at least:
        var http = require('http'),
        var util = require('util');

I'm not familiar with that specific NPM (formidable) but by checking out its documentation quickly I did not seem to notice that includes things like response so how is response defined? Sorry if this does not lead you to the correct response but going by what I see as potential problems.
*You could also try what the other commenter said to try to fix your non string problem if that's the problem.*

Also anything after response.end I believe won't be seen. Try to console.log ( before that)... also you can just use `response.end(id---if id was a string)` rather than `response.write("this string");` then `response.end();` response end can include a response write.